# $\sup\limits_{y\in [0,1]\setminus\{x\}}\left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right|\in \mathbb{R}_+$ continuous?

Tags: metric-spaces

> Is this function $f\in(\mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R}),\|\cdot\|_\infty)\mapsto B(f)=\sup\limits_{y\in [0,1]\setminus\{x\}}\left|\dfrac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right|\in \mathbb{R}_+$ continuous?

I think if I reduce this metric space $(\mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R}),\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ to $E'=\{f\in \mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R}); \;f(0)=0\}$ then $B$ is a norm.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543327/

Comment: Is $x$ just some fixed number? In either case, that supremum need not be finite.

Comment: the supremum is finite because we have $x\ne y$

Comment: @Stu then the expression is well-defined but still it won't be finite in general.